# How to properly load mongodb module? ( Uncaught Error: Module name "mongodb" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([]) )

Tags: javascript, python, node.js, mongodb, flask

I'm trying to do a web page on Flask that uses a mongodb database but I can't connect. If I just run my python scripts all is fine I can connect to the database, create documents and read them but on the Flask side it doesn't seem to work.
Everything else on the Javascript side works just fine besides connecting to the database.
I used: https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_mongodb.asp to connect.
I installed node.js that includes npm: https://nodejs.org/en/download/ from here.

Here is my sources:

```
   <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Publisher</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/r.js"></script>
    </head>
```

Here is the script for connecting to the database:

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:56215/9414efbc-92ee-41a4-8666-3f98c5b6ec99?" //Temporary change it each time
var DB_Data = []

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("IOT_Modbus_DB");
  dbo.collection("IOT_Modbus_Coll").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    DB_Data = result;
    if (err) throw err;
    db.close();
  });
});
```

Will Result in this error:

```
r.js:417 Uncaught Error: Module name "mongodb" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded
    at makeError (r.js:417)
    at Object.localRequire [as require] (r.js:1685)
    at requirejs (r.js:2046)
    at update:50
```

If I do what it recommends meaning this:

```
var MongoClient = require(['mongodb']).MongoClient;
```

I get this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'connect' of undefined
    at update:54
r.js:2420 GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/mongodb.js 404 (NOT FOUND)
require.load @ r.js:2420
load @ r.js:1934
load @ r.js:1083
fetch @ r.js:1073
check @ r.js:1105
enable @ r.js:1425
enable @ r.js:1806
(anonymous) @ r.js:1410
(anonymous) @ r.js:383
each @ r.js:308
enable @ r.js:1362
init @ r.js:1037
(anonymous) @ r.js:1709
setTimeout (async)
req.nextTick @ r.js:2064
localRequire @ r.js:1698
requirejs @ r.js:2046
(anonymous) @ update:50
VM639:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
    at exec (r.js:2413)
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhr.onreadystatechange (r.js:2424)
Uncaught Error: Load timeout for modules: mongodb
https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#timeout
    at makeError (r.js:417)
    at checkLoaded (r.js:947)
    at r.js:968
```

From what I read the proper way to do it is without the "[]" but I tried just in case. I should mention I have no mongodb.js file since I worked in a single html file. I also tried what other answers suggested from people that had similar errors but it didn't work.
I also tried what said here: https://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#notloaded besides putting it into a function but I'm not sure how go about that.
What am I missing? How am I supposed to load it for context?

Below I will put the Flask python file just in case. Also the complete html file.

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, jsonify
import json
import Modbus_Gw_Parsed
import Monitor_Host_Parsed
import pyModbus_Client
import DB_Modbus

app = Flask(__name__)

#TODO: calling

@app.route('/')
def Publisher_Display():
        return render_template('Publisher_Display.html')

@app.route('/update')
def update():
    Modbus_Gw_Parsed.runGw()
    Monitor_Host_Parsed.runHost()
    pyModbus_Client.runMod()
    DB_Modbus.Create_Db()
    return render_template('Publisher_Display.html')
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
  app.config['TEMPLATES_AUTO_RELOAD'] = True
  app.config['SEND_FILE_MAX_AGE_DEFAULT'] = 0
  app.run()
```

Publisher_Display.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<style>
    canvas {
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
</style>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Publisher</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.2/Chart.bundle.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.6/r.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
<!-- This will update the output files -->
<form action = "/update">
    <input type="submit" value="Fetch New Data">
</form>
<!--backend.py -->

    <div id="myData"></div>
    <div style="width:75%;">
        <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    </div>
<script>
    Promise.all([
    //Configuration Data: Represent the meaning of the important data
    fetch('/static/Monitor_Host_Publishers_Parsed.json').then(resp => resp.json()),
    fetch('/static/Modbus_Gw_File_Parsed.json').then(resp => resp.json()),
    //Publish Data: Display graphically
    fetch('/static/pyModbus.json').then(resp => resp.json())
          ]).then(function (data) {
                appendData(data);
                console.log(data);
                chart(data);
            })
            .catch(function (err) {
                console.log('error: ' + err);
            });

//MongoDB
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = "mongodb://127.0.0.1:56215/9414efbc-92ee-41a4-8666-3f98c5b6ec99?" //Temporary change it each time
var DB_Data = []

MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db) {
  if (err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db("IOT_Modbus_DB");
  dbo.collection("IOT_Modbus_Coll").find({}).toArray(function(err, result) {
    DB_Data = result;
    if (err) throw err;
    db.close();
  });
});

function appendData(data){
//Representing configuration data
  var mainContainer = document.getElementById("myData");
      var ip;
      for(var i=0; i<data[1].length; i++){
          ip = data[1][i].Eui64;
          console.log(ip+': '+i)
          var div = document.createElement("div");
          div.innerHTML = '<br/>Address: '+data[1][i].start_addr+
                          '<br/>Number of Registers: '+data[1][i].word_cnt+
                          '<br/>Device: '+ip+
                          '<br/>Unit of measurement: '+data[0][ip].channel[0].unit_of_measurement+
                          '<br/>Status: '+data[0][ip].channel[0].withStatus+'<br/>_';   
          mainContainer.appendChild(div);
      }  
}

function state_bulb(data){
//Temporary(?) State Checker    
//TODO: Show status
reg1 = data[1][0].status; // if is 2 the last register will represent the status
reg2 = data[1][1].status; // and not sensor value
/*
128 - Data is Fresh (green)
20 - Data is stale (yellow)
0 - Missing data or connection (red)
*/
}

function chart(data){
//Publish Data Chart
window.chartColors = {  red: 'rgb(255, 0, 0)',  green: 'rgb(0, 128, 0)', yellow: 'rgb(200, 200, 0)' }; 

var randomScalingFactor = function() {
            return Math.round(Math.random() * 100);
        };

var today = new Date();
var labelnames = [today.getHours() + ":" + today.getMinutes() + ":" + today.getSeconds()];
    
var count = data[2][0].response.length; //TODO: Make a max function to compare all data[2] lengths

var config = {
        type: 'line',
        data: { //TODO: Make number of datasets scale-able
            labels: labelnames,
            datasets: [{
                label: 'Register ' +data[2][0].register,
                data: DB_Data[0].Value,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.green,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                fill: false,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
            }, {
                label: 'Register ' +data[2][1].register,
                data: DB_Data[1].Value,
                borderColor: window.chartColors.red,
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)',
                fill: false,
                cubicInterpolationMode: 'monotone'
            }]
        },
        options: {
            responsive: true,
            title: {
                display: true,
                text: 'Configuration Chart'
            },
            tooltips: {
                mode: 'index'
            },
            scales: {
                xAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true
                    }
                }],
                yAxes: [{
                    display: true,
                    scaleLabel: {
                        display: true,
                        labelString: 'Value'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        suggestedMin: 0,
                        suggestedMax: 100,
                    }
                }]
            }
        },      
    };

var ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out but only partially.
Because I am using flask I cannot use mongodb directly in js.

I have to pass the collection or any other variable when I render the html like so:

```
app = Flask(__name__)

    title = "IOT Project"
    
    client = MongoClient("mongodb://127.0.0.1:5000") #placeholder
    db = client["IOT_Modbus_DB"]
    col = client["IOT_Modbus_Coll"]
    
    @app.route('/')
    def Publisher_Display():
            return render_template('Publisher_Display.html', Data = col, t = title)
```

It's pretty easy to call them in HTML afterwards

```
<title>{{t}}</title>
```

This would give the title sent as "t" when rendering.
I will update this answer if I figure out how to send specific data from the database.

EDIT:
Pretty simple actually:

```
for x in col.find({ "Register": "1020000000000061" },{"_id": 0}):
  Reg1.append(x)
```

This is how mongodb handles find. "_id": 0 simply means that it won't show the id. After you send that variable when rendering just be sure to do it like this:

```
{{ var | safe }}
```

if you have strings because if you do it like this:

```
{{ var }}
```

You will get encoded &#39 instead of " or '